# PrimeFaces 3.5 parameter.DIR dynamically

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

Trying to make the new RTL Support in **PrimeFaces 3.5** work **dynamically**, I appended the following in **web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>primefaces.DIR</param-name>
      <param-value>#{facesBean.direction}</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

As you can see, the parameter value is an EL **expression**, evaluated from the bean property : direction:

```
    private String direction = "ltr";
    //......

    public String getDirection() {
          if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale().getLanguage() == "ar") {
             direction = "rtl";
          } else {
             direction = "ltr";
          }
          return direction;


}
```

However this does not work (I am too naive to believe it could work that simple way, since web.xml is not loaded the same way as xhtml files...)

If I tell explicitly for example ACCORDION to react to direction value, it **does successfully** (If locale language is changed to ar, dir receives rtl value, and if it is changed to fr or en, value received by dir attribute is ltr):

```
<p:accordionPanel dir="#{facesBean.direction}" id="accordion_services" dynamic="true" cache="true"
                                  style="text-align: justify;" >
                    <p:tab title="#{i18n.seep}">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
<!-- Remainder of code here ...... -->
```

I could apply that latter solution to every PrimeFaces component that has the DIR attribute, but that is anti-productive and would consume great amount of time.
The application scope DIR parameter is the ideal solution and it's claimed that it supports EL expressions. So I am interested in making it work.

Any clues?

### Thanks.

JBoss AS 7.1
Mojarra 2.1
PrimeFaces 3.5
Latest Firefox/Chrome

---

**Reference:** Page 491 from PrimeFaces 3.5 user guide:

*Global Configuration

Using primefaces.DIR global setting to rtl instructs PrimeFaces RTL aware components such as datatable, accordion, tabview, dialog, tree to render in RTL mode.*

```
`<context-param>     

<param-name>primefaces.DIR</param-name>

<param-value>rtl</param-value> 

</context-param>`
```

*Parameter value can also be an EL expression for dynamic values. In upcoming PrimeFaces releases, more components will receive built-in RTL support. Until then if the component you use doesn’t provide it, overriding css and javascript in your application would be the solution. 
491*

Comment: have you come to solution with this issue ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh not really! the DIRECTIOn in WEB.XML is loaded at runtime! It's not dynamic! So as for now, I am just using the "dir" attribute of every component which retrieves its value from the method public String getDirection(){}. I posted this matter in PrimeFaces forum but no answer since months!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTL currently does NOT support EL in web.xml (I am using PF 3.5)
I have created a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6072&thanks=6072&ts=1377986205) for PF team

I have posted this question again in PF forum and I got an answer [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33553)

See also:

[using JSF EL expression inside web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519272/using-jsf-el-expression-inside-web-xml)

**UPDATE**
its fixed and will be available in the upcoming Primefaces 4.1