# using JSF EL expression inside web.xml

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, el

Can I use EL expression inside web.xml ?
Like this

Web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.DIR</param-name>
        <param-value>#{userUtilityBacking.direction}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and my JSF bean like this

JSF bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="userUtilityBacking")
@SessionScoped
public class UserUtilityBacking  implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String direction  ;   
// and public setters and getter
```

Will it work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Can I use EL expression inside web.xml ?*

Not exactly that. By default, the servletcontainer doesn't EL-evaluate the context parameters when the `web.xml` is been parsed during application startup. However, build tools like Ant and Maven and some servletcontainers like JBoss (after setting a specific configuration setting) support using `${...}` syntax similar to EL to inline environment variables and/or VM arguments by their name in several deployment descriptor XML files such as `web.xml`, `ejb-jar.xml` and `persistence.xml`. Note: that are thus **not** those variables which you've declared in JSF EL scope, such as managed bean.

---

> *Will it work ?*

It will only work if PrimeFaces gets the static value `"#{userUtilityBacking.direction}"` as `String` and then programmatically EL-evaluates it in the current EL context using for example [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29). But, based on the [PrimeFaces 3.5 source code](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/util/ComponentUtils.java?spec=svn8519&r=8519#425), it is not doing that anywhere. It look like they implemented it for 4.x only.

In your particular case, you'd better just specify the direction directly on `<html>` element to apply it document-wide and/or in `dir` attribute of an arbitrary HTML or JSF component.

```
<html dir="#{userUtilityBacking.direction}">
```

Comment: You are right for sure, but what confused me is what I found in PrimeFaces documentation ... " Using primefaces.DIR global setting to rtl instructs PrimeFaces RTL aware components to render in RTL mode. Parameter value can also be an EL expression for dynamic values " , I dont know what they mean by this

Comment: I have created a feature request for this https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6072&thanks=6072&ts=1377986205